# Is it possible to compute an inverse of sparse matrix in Python as fast as in Matlab?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, numpy, sparse-matrix

It takes 0.02 seconds for Matlab to compute the inverse of a diagonal matrix using the sparse command.

```
P = diag(1:10000);
P = sparse(P);
tic;
A = inv(P);
toc
```

However, for the Python code it takes forever - several minutes.

```
import numpy as np
import time

startTime = time.time()
P = np.diag(range(1,10000))
A = np.linalg.inv(P)
runningTime = (time.time()-startTime)/60
print "The script was running for %f minutes" % runningTime
```

I tried to use Scipy.sparse module but it did not help. The running time dropped, but only to 40 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import scipy.sparse as sps
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spsl

startTime = time.time()
P = np.diag(range(1,10000))
P_sps = sps.coo_matrix(P)
A = spsl.inv(P_sps)
runningTime = (time.time()-startTime)/60
print "The script was running for %f minutes" % runningTime
```

Is it possible to run the code as fast as it runs in Matlab?

Comment: storing the matrix as P_sps = sps.dia_matrix(P) makes a little bit of improvement but Matlab code is still 3 orders faster

Comment: The real question is why you feel the need to invert a matrix.

Comment: As Heffernan said, do you actually need to invert the matrix? See [this](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/) and [this](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/08/10/do-you-really-need-to-compute-that-matrix-inverse/) for a few posts

Comment: In the matlab code you start to count the time after creating the diagonal and converting the matrix to sparse. In the python codes you do it before. You are not comparing in a fair way.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the time you spend creating a 2D array of size 10000x10000, storing the diagonal, and converting it to csr is much biger than the time you spend inverting the diagonal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer. When you run inv in matlab for a sparse matrix, matlab check different properties of the matrix to optimize the calculation. For a sparse diagonal matrix, you can run the followin code to see what is matlab doing

```
n = 10000;
a = diag(1:n);
a = sparse(a);
I = speye(n,n);
spparms('spumoni',1);
ainv = inv(a);
spparms('spumoni',0);
```

Matlab will print the following:

```
sp\: bandwidth = 0+1+0.
sp\: is A diagonal? yes.
sp\: do a diagonal solve.
```

So matlab is inverting only the diagonal.

How does Scipy invert the matrix??
Here we have the [code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py#L37):

```
...
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
...

def inv(A):
    """
    Some comments...
    """
    I = speye(A.shape[0], A.shape[1], dtype=A.dtype, format=A.format)
    Ainv = spsolve(A, I)
    return Ainv
```

and [spsolve](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L149)

```
    # Cover the case where b is also a matrix
    Afactsolve = factorized(A)
    tempj = empty(M, dtype=int)
    x = A.__class__(b.shape)
    for j in range(b.shape[1]):
        xj = Afactsolve(squeeze(b[:, j].toarray()))
        w = where(xj != 0.0)[0]
        tempj.fill(j)
        x = x + A.__class__((xj[w], (w, tempj[:len(w)])),
                            shape=b.shape, dtype=A.dtype)
```

i.e., scipy factorize A and then solve a set of linear systems where the right hand sides are the coordinate vectors (forming the identity matrix). Ordering all the solutions in a matrix we obtain the inverse of the initial matrix.

If matlab is taken advantage of the diagonal structure of the matrix, but scipy is not (of course scipy is also using the structure of the matrix, but in a less efficient way, at least for the example), matlab should be much faster.

**EDIT**
To be sure, as @P.Escondido propossed, we will try a minor modification in matrix A, to trace the matlab procedure when the matrix is not diagonal:

```
n = 10000; a = diag(1:n); a = sparse(a); ainv = sparse(n,n);
spparms('spumoni',1);
a(100,10) = 500; a(10,1000) = 200; 
ainv = inv(a);
spparms('spumoni',0);
```

It prints out the following:

```
sp\: bandwidth = 90+1+990.
sp\: is A diagonal? no.
sp\: is band density (0.00) > bandden (0.50) to try banded solver? no.
sp\: is A triangular? no.
sp\: is A morally triangular? yes.
sp\: permute and solve.
sp\: sprealloc in sptsolve: 10000 10000 10000 15001
```

Comment: thanks!

please add

    a(1000,10)=500;
    a(10,1000)=200;

to the solution and the corresponding output. It gives us a much better understanding of how Matlab actually works.

If you do, I'll mark the problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

How about `splu()`, it's faster but need a dense array and return dense array:

Create a random matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import scipy.sparse as sps
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spsl
from numpy.random import randint
N = 1000
i = np.arange(N)
j = np.arange(N)
v = np.ones(N)

i2 = randint(0, N, N)
j2 = randint(0, N, N)
v2 = np.random.rand(N)

i = np.concatenate((i, i2))
j = np.concatenate((j, j2))
v = np.concatenate((v, v2))

A = sps.coo_matrix((v, (i, j)))
A = A.tocsc()

%time B = spsl.inv(A)
```

calculate inverse matrix by `splu()`:

```
%%time
lu = spsl.splu(A)
eye = np.eye(N)
B2 = lu.solve(eye)
```

check the result:

```
np.allclose(B.todense(), B2.T)
```

Here is the %time output:

```
inv: 2.39 s
splv: 193 ms
```

Comment: the code does not compile in Python 2.7; the problem is in " %time B = spsl.inv(A)". What compiler should I use?

Comment: %time is IPython command, if you don't use IPython, just remove %time and %%time.

Answer (score 3):

You are witholding crucial information from your software: the fact that the matrix is diagonal makes it super easy to invert: you simply invert each element of its diagonal:

```
P = np.diag(range(1,10000))
A = np.diag(1.0/np.arange(1,10000))
```

Of course, this is only valid for diagonal matrices...

Comment: Exactly, this is only valid for diagonal matrices, therefore the answer does not really work. Please also note that I do not have to specify my knowledge of the structure to Matlab.

Comment: @P.Escondido I spend a little time trying to understand and reverse-engineer what Matlab does when it invert a matrix. I must say the floks at mathworks did a very good job on that subject. Behind the scenes there are quite a few numerical libraries at play taking advantage of the matrix's specific characteristics. If you can supply this extra info to your program - make yourself an easy life and use it, don't try to solve over-complicated problems if you don't have to...

Answer (score 0):

If you try with that the result will be better:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import scipy.sparse as sps
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spsl

P = np.diag(range(1,10000))
P_sps = sps.coo_matrix(P)
startTime = time.time()
A = spsl.inv(P_sps)
runningTime = (time.time()-startTime)/60
print "The script was running for %f minutes" % runningTime
```

Now you can compare with your matlab script.

Comment: thanks, I agree that timer should have been started right before the computation, but the difference is neglible

Comment: I do not think the difference is negligible.

Comment: 0.44 vs 0.64 minutes. Matlab does it 3 orders faster. In this sense, it's negligible.