# Inverting large arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy, inversion

I have two arrays `R3_mod` with shape `(21,21)` containing many zeros and `P2` with shape `(21,)` containing many zeros. I am getting the inverse of  `R3_mod` using `np.linalg.pinv()` and eventually multiplying it to `P2` as shown below. Is there a more efficient way to invert such arrays and then multiply?

Since the arrays are too big, you can access it here: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1NjEiNoneMaCbmbmObEs2GCNIb08NFIy3

```
import numpy as np
X = np.linalg.pinv(R3_mod).dot(P2)
```

Comment: I do not think `21x21` is a large matrix. Its conditioning is more relevant for accurate results. Use `sparse` module in `scipy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compute an inverse of sparse matrix in Python as fast as in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693613/is-it-possible-to-compute-an-inverse-of-sparse-matrix-in-python-as-fast-as-in-ma)

Comment: While your array is singular, with lots of 0s, the `pinv` isn't nearly as sparse, is it?  It may still be singular.

Comment: For ```21x21```  it works fine. But if I want to go higher, say ```10000x10000```, ```pinv``` doesn't yield reasonable output.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the matrix R3_mod is indeed invertible, I think it's best to use np.linalg.inv instead of linalg.pinv.

inv computes the inverse of the matrix directly, where pinv (stands for pseudo-inverse, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) computes the matrix A' that minimizes |AA'-I|. If the input matrix is invertible, pinv should return the same result as inv.

Comment: His matrix is singular - at least on row is all 0s.